How can I create a repeating pattern in shader editor using the Brick Texture shader node?
I can generate different-colored squares with the Brick Texture shader node outputting to color ramp to restrict it to only black or white. However, I need a specific, repeating pattern like this:
0,1,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0

Is there a way to achieve this structured, non-randomized pattern with the Brick Texture shader node, or would I need to use another method? Note: the mortar is desired in this case


You could let a non-random Voronoi texture do most of the maths for you.. that's quite often a lazy way to tiling.
Your pattern is a checker (X+Y mod 2) unmasked at Y mod 3, with distance-to-edge for the mortar:



